# dble clicking the drag down only auto fills 100 or so rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to drag a function down all of the rows (30000) rows for example

the double click feature is only filling the first 100 rows

Answer (score 0):

Double click should fill all the way down unless there are gaps in your data.

If there are gaps in your data you will need to find the last row yourself press ctrl+shift+up to select the column up to your original cell and then ctrl+d to fill down.

Answer (score 0):

The fill handle will fill to the end of the current region, as recognized by Excel. If you have data down to only row 100 in a neighbouring column, then Excel sees that as the current region and the fill handle will only fill to row 100 and it may be a bit of work to make it go all the way to row 30000.

Try this:

- Let's say the formula is in B3 and there's nothing below it.
- Hit F5 to open the Go To dialog
- enter the cell address where you want the formula to be copied to, for example B30000.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to select all cells from B30000 to B3 (which has the formula). The active cell is B30000.
- with the selection still active, hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. That will move the active cell to the top (you can omit that step, but I like to see I have the correct starting cell).
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to copy the formula all the way down the selected cells.